# How to generate _id on conflict during replication of cloudant databases?

Tags: cloudant

While using the replication API https://docs.cloudant.com/replication_guide.html how to instruct cloudant to generate a new _id when there is a conflict?

Basically I have to merge documents from one database to another one ... I will specify "doc_ids" to replicate ... But if there is a conflict I want cloudant to generate a new _id and proceed on. Is this possible?

Comment: If Cloudant is like CouchDB you will need to listen for conflicts on changes feed and update the documents in conflict yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cloudant, as with CouchDB, doesn't have any means to handle conflicts on your behalf. What this means is you'll need to handle this in your application code, which you can do my listening to the `changes` feed. If you are new to conflicts and conflict resolution you can use these guides.

https://cloudant.com/blog/introduction-to-document-conflicts-part-one/

https://cloudant.com/blog/introduction-to-document-conflicts-part-two/

https://cloudant.com/blog/introduction-to-document-conflicts-part-three/

Comment: If i use the query params "_changes?filter=_doc_ids&doc_ids=00087383d5fbddb5877b19fcd14fdc47&include_docs=true&conflicts=true I get an error {"error":"bad_request","reason":"filter parameter must be of the form `designname/filtername`"}

Comment: That would be because the filter parameter is for specifying a filter function, see the documentation for [_changes](https://docs.cloudant.com/database.html#get-changes)